# How is SSO with Azure AD and Microsoft Graph API actually done?

Tags: .net, azure

I was looking into *SSO* with *Azure AD* for a customer, and Microsoft seems to push towards the new *Graph API*.

Their [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/plan-sso-deployment) says that if your app/website authenticates with a password, you should do password authentication with the graph api.

But when going to the api reference, [they say it's not available yet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/authenticationmethods-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0).

So, how would we go about it, if at all?
Is it possible to integrate an existing login form with Azure AD?
Is it possible to auto-detect the current windows domain user to bypass the login form, like the old days with on-prem AD?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to integrate an existing login form with Azure AD?

Yes it is possible to integrate an existing login form with Azure AD provided the application for which you want to configure SSO is register in your Azure AD as an enterprise application .

For this you will have to register the application in Azure AD.
For more information please refer this  MSDOC: [***`Enable single sign-on for an enterprise application`***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/add-application-portal-setup-sso)

> Is it possible to auto-detect the current windows domain user to
> bypass the login form, like the old days with on-prem AD?

Yes, Once the SSO has been configured for that enterprise application you can by-pass the login form for that application ,once the user has logged into the device through which it is accessing that application. For this purpose device needs to be join with Azure AD.

In case if you want to configure SSO for your Application through ***Graph API*** ,Kindly refer the below link for implementation/reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/application-saml-sso-configure-api

Comment: Thank you. This is for a multi-tenant situation. Do you have any info on how the SSO is done? Do customers need a browser extension to add a special header?

Comment: Hello @daniel.gindi, could you please refer this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65654738/identifying-and-filtering-tenants-using-multi-tenant-azure-ad-sso-open-id-conne

Comment: Not really answering my question :-) Let's say a user is logged in to his domain on Windows, and goes to our sass site in the browser. How would our site detect that he is already logged in to the domain?

Comment: I see in MSAL.NET that they have "AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuth", and they say it "pulls from the operating system". And I guess that's either for a program running locally, or the browser sending a special header. But the browser cannot just send the header everywhere as it will be used for tracking, so the IT manager can probably define which sites receives those headers? How do we use this with MSAL.NET?

Comment: The user who  is logged into his domain on Windows OS , and tries to logged into the SAAS website in the browser retrieves the `deviceauthtoken` from the `AzureAD` joined device . Also when we configure SSO for SAAS website in Azure AD the redirection to that SAAS website ,after authentication happens according to the authentication protocol configured for it. For more information please refer this MS DOC:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/hybrid-azuread-join-federated-domains